# The filter section gives a error by next page

Tags: php, woocommerce

(
You can have a look to the page by here: http://www.myfoon.nl/telefoons/?filter_merk=100
)

When I want to go the to next second page of the shop page it gives a error.

It seems easy to fix but haven't found the problem.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

your href is linked to this url `http://www.myfoon.nl/telefoons/page/2/filter_merk=100`

which does not exist. Modify the href and put a valid url there.

Comment: Do you maybe know where can I modify the url?

Comment: I don't know the structure of woo_commerce but there is a lot of information in the internet. Try look for "replace href from product list in woo_commerce". There are many info's and suggestions try the one that fits you.The reason your page fails is the href for sure so focus there.